# How to resolve black screen in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabbar

I am using a TabBar in my App . When I open my application It gives black screen  . I using server images for tab icon. I have used postDelayed method with Handler But still it gives black screen. Plz tell me how i can resolve this problem from my app.

Log errors are:- 
Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{409d1880 com.educated/.screens.More}

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Use class **AsyncTask** and load your images in **doInBackground()** method.

Comment: This. It should give you a couple of errors since you are using the network is the main thread. This is the UI thread, it should never be used to do lenghtly work (intense calculation, network, ...). If you target a recent version of Android (and it is a very good practice to always target the last version of Android) you should get NetworkOnMainThread exceptions where you are doing this mistake.